# Extracting specific value from a table

Tags: kdb

I have the tabe:

```
As: 11 43 23 67 76 
Bs: 87 38 70 8 10 
syms:A`B where 4 4
AA:([] A:As;B:Bs)
1#select A from AA
```

I get the output

```
A 
--
11
```

I would like to know how to just have the value returned instead of having the output to be a table? So, in this case, it would just return 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of numerous ways to do this

```
q)AA[0]`A
11
```

to get last item

```
q)last[AA]`A
76
```

or both at once

```
q)(first;last)@\:AA`A
11 76
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I wanted the last item of the column A, how would I do it? I tried using negative indexing which doesn't work so wondering if this is possible.

Comment: edited my original post

Comment: thanks, but I was thinking of adding it to the same line of code. For example,
AA[0,n;`A] where n is the last element. Ideally, I would not have to key in n manually every time n changes.

Comment: edited my OR again

Comment: You can index as you imagined: ``AA[0,count[AA]-1;`A]`` but the Each Left expression is better.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `exec` keyword instead of `select` when you want column values as a list:

```
1#exec A from AA
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using exec instead of select, which will return just the value in a list.

Note: If the query is in a hdb / on a partitioned db then you'll need to select first then exec.